# Calculando um valor proporcional a data do mês

Tags: php

Galera estou montando um script em `php` que vai ser executado no 1º dia de cada mês, gerando uma conta a receber com base um valor de **120,00**. Ou seja no primeiro dia de cada mês ele cria uma conta de **120,00**.

O problema é que, se o cliente começar a utilizar o serviço no dia 15 ou em qualquer outro dia, ele tem que pagar um valor proporcional aos dias que ele utilizou. Isso é simples, eu divido os 120,00 pelos dias do mês e depois multiplico pelos dias usados. O problema é que não tenho ideia de como recuperar os dias usados.

Se alguém puder me ajudar.

Segue as variáveis com os dados que recupero do BD.

```
$valor_mensalidade = 120;
$data_inicio = "2016-06-15";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viva,

O que pensei foi: saber quantos dias tinha esse mês.. dividir o valor pelos dias do mês.. depois multiplicar o resultado pelos meses passados..

```
$valueMonth = 120;
$dateInit = '2016-06-15';
$totalDays = date('t', strtotime($dateInit));
$used = date('d', strtotime($dateInit));
$result = ($valueMonth/$totalDays)*$used;
```

Acho que é isso que pretendes, se não avisa ;)

Abraço

Comment: Bom não funcionou muito bem. Veja bem coloquei o seguinte valor ($dateInit = '2016-06-01';) sendo que hoje é dias 09 correto, então o valor no $result tinha que ser 36,00.

Comment: Aqui deu 36.. http://pastebin.com/R3UwWaEM

Comment: para mim esta retornando 4. $valueMonth = 120;
$dateInit = '2016-06-01';
$totalDays = date('t', strtotime($dateInit));
$used = date('d', strtotime($dateInit));
$result = ($valueMonth/$totalDays)*$used;
 
echo $result;

Comment: Se a date init for 01, nao precisa fazer contas :) O date init é a data do registo do utilizador..

Comment: aff fiz confusão hahahah, deu certo aqui muito obrigado

Comment: como eu faria para ter uma variável e inicio e fim? ou seja para ele calcular em um perigo de data?